# Split rows but maintain labels

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to literally split some of the values in a dataframe, but would like to maintain some of the labels while allowing for one new label for the new splits. For example:

```
day    year    depth    mass 
1      2008    10       13
2      2008    10       15
1      2008    20       14
2      2008    20       12
1      2009    10       14
2      2009    10       16
1      2009    20       12
2      2009    20       18
```

Now divide each mass by 2 to get:

```
day    year    depth    mass 
1      2008    10a      6.5
1      2008    10b      6.5
2      2008    10a      7.5
2      2008    10b      7.5
1      2008    20a      7
1      2008    20b      7
2      2008    20a      6
2      2008    20b      6
1      2009    10a      7
1      2009    10b      7
2      2009    10a      8
2      2009    10b      8   
1      2009    20a      6
1      2009    20b      6  
2      2009    20a      9 
2      2009    20b      9
```

There are new values, but they have the corresponding day and year data.

To make things more complicated, I will be running a slightly different function on each depth.  For example, I will divide depth == 10 by 2, but depth == 20 by three.  But I can probably figure that out if the basic question here can be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A somewhat long data.table line, but I think this will achieve what you need:

```
library(data.table)
df$id <- rownames(df)
df1 <- setDT(df)[rep(1:nrow(df),times = 2),.SD,by=id][,`:=`(mass=mass/2,depth=paste(depth,c("a","b"),sep=""))]
```

Output:

```
df1

id day year depth mass
1   1 2008   10a  6.5
1   1 2008   10b  6.5
2   2 2008   10a  7.5
2   2 2008   10b  7.5
3   1 2008   20a  7.0
3   1 2008   20b  7.0
4   2 2008   20a  6.0
4   2 2008   20b  6.0
5   1 2009   10a  7.0
5   1 2009   10b  7.0
6   2 2009   10a  8.0
6   2 2009   10b  8.0
7   1 2009   20a  6.0
7   1 2009   20b  6.0
8   2 2009   20a  9.0
8   2 2009   20b  9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr, you can do this way:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(day, year, depth) %>% bind_rows(., .) %>% mutate(mass = mass/2) %>% arrange(day, year, depth, mass)
```

Note, I have not done the a/b appending to the depth, but I think you can probably do it based on this same idea.

Output is as follows:

```
Source: local data frame [16 x 4]

     day  year depth  mass
   (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
1      1  2008    10   6.5
2      1  2008    10   6.5
3      1  2008    20   7.0
4      1  2008    20   7.0
5      1  2009    10   7.0
6      1  2009    10   7.0
7      1  2009    20   6.0
8      1  2009    20   6.0
9      2  2008    10   7.5
10     2  2008    10   7.5
11     2  2008    20   6.0
12     2  2008    20   6.0
13     2  2009    10   8.0
14     2  2009    10   8.0
15     2  2009    20   9.0
16     2  2009    20   9.0
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but the other is more complete.